# How do I trace the GET request from this html code?

Tags: html, http

After hitting the submit in by filling the below form,

```
<h1>Our Contact Form</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action="process_form.php" method="get">
            <p>
            Title: <input type="radio" name="title" value="mr"> Mr 
                   <input type="radio" name="title" value="mrs"> Mrs
            </p>
            <p>
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" size="15" name="first_name">
            </p>
            <p>
                Sur name:<br>
                <input type="text" size="15" name="surname">
            </p>
            <p>
                Gender:
                <select>
                    <option value="select">Select Gender</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter"> Subscribe to my news letter
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>        
        </form>
```

Syntax for GET: `request-method-name request-URI HTTP-version`

How would I trace the GET command request sent from the chrome browser? Do we have any option under  F12 screen of chrome browser?

*Note: Beginner*

Comment: using `$_GET['{field-name}']` after form submission

Comment: Depends on your browser, but generally, yes.

Comment: @CodeCaster  When I execute this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/79Lk4ztf/), I want to see how the `get` request header and request body is created. Where is the uploaded file located in get request? Where are comments located in get request? after you click submit button. Do you understand my question?GET request structure is shown [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trace HTTP requests, check the network tab in the developer tools in Chrome.

Update:  For file-uploads, you should use POST instead of GET.  Furthermore, you need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form.

See the updated fiddle with the required changes: http://jsfiddle.net/79Lk4ztf/1/

Here's a screenshot where of a POST request I made using the form in your fiddle.  Under "Request Payload" you can see the data in the request, as it's constructed when using multipart/form-data

[image: Screenshot showing the dev tools in Chrome]

How you access the data depends on the server-side technology you are using.  If you are using PHP, then you need to use `$_POST['first_name']` to get the first name and `$_FILES['data']` to access the uploaded file.

If you are using ASP.NET, you can use `Request.Form["first_name"]` and `Request.Files["data"]` to access the same information, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows all requests, also any resources/pages your page contains.  You can filter the requests and what you most likely want to see is "Documents".

Comment: minus one, your answer is not useful

Comment: Well I'm sorry I tried to help.  You asked where requests could be traced and I told you exactly where that can be done.

Comment: When I execute this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/79Lk4ztf/), I want to see how the `get` request header and request body is created. Where is the uploaded file located in get request? Where are comments located in get request? after you click submit button. Do you understand my question?GET request structure is shown [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html)

Comment: I see. You cannot upload files using GET.  You need to change your form to use POST and you also need to specify enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form.   I'm currently writing this on my phone, I can update my answer and provide more details later when I get back in front of my computer.

Comment: What is enctype?significance?

Comment: It's used to control the encoding of the form data, i.e the way the browser formats the data in the request body.  When uploading files, you need to specify multipart/form-data as the enctype of the form.  If you omit that, the file will not be sent over, but the regular input fields will.

Comment: The reason, I could not see the form fields as you shown in this screenshot is because I did not have any php code. Once I deploy the php code, I guess, I can trace Network tab. So, Can share the php code to process this [form](http://jsfiddle.net/79Lk4ztf/2/)?